# class validator stop at first does not work as stated in documentation

Tags: javascript, typescript, nest, class-validator

I have a Dto class which I am using for validation. I have a global Validation Pipe with the property stopAtFirstError set to true. When I run code, Validation decorators get executed even after the first decorator returns an error message.

Nest.js Main.ts File

```
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
      stopAtFirstError: true
    }),
  );
```

Dto Class used for validation.

```
export class LeaveApplicationBodyDto {
  @ValidateIf((o) => regualarLeaves.includes(o.type))
  @IsRequired()
  @IsUniqueDate()
  @ValidateNested({ each: true })
  @Type(() => LeaveMetadata)
  metadata: LeaveMetadata[];

  @IsString()
  @IsIn([...regualarLeaves, ...specialLeaves])
  type: string;

  @ValidateIf((o) => specialLeaves.includes(o.type))
  @IsYYYYMMDDFormat()
  @IsString()
  @IsNotHoliday()
  startDate: String;

  @IsString()
  remark: string;
}
```

Here `@IsRequired()` and `@IsuniqueDate()` is custom decorator made for validation purpose.
IsRequired returns false if metadata property is not sent through POST request body. After `IsRequired()` return false code moves to `IsUnique()`  which check an array of the object through`.map()` method provided by JS. Due to lack of early termination of code error is thrown `cannot read property of undefined`

The question is why `StopAtFirstError:true` is not working as expected or Am I missing something.

Answer (score 0):

stopAtFirstError works when you have the decorator order correctly to produce the expected result. Generally decorator works in reverse order.

For example:

```
@A()
@B()
function test() {}
```

this will be evaluate into

```
A(B(test()))
```

So inner (nearer/closer) to the function will be executed first and vice versa.

Read more on [official Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-composition)